# Was "Fyodor in Crime" a reference to Dostoevsky?

Tags: russian-language, andrey-kurkov, death-and-the-penguin

In *Death and the Penguin*, the newspaper editor told Viktor to contact Fyodor from *Crime* for some information to help him with his writing.

Is this a subtle reference to *Crime and Punishment* by Fyodor Dostoevsky?